# Google Calendar Watch on a desktop app

Tags: c#, vb.net, google-calendar-api, watch

I can not find any examples of how to create a request "watch" on events. It essential to have a secure domain (https) ? I would like to create a "listener" independent of my external domain. Is there anyone who can tell me an example ? In vb or c # .net it is the same.
On the official guide unfortunately there is not much about it.

Thank you !

Comment: "put on hold": I think instead that the request, especially because it has only one possible answer ("it is not possible"), could not be more specific. There are dozens of examples of how to accomplish this procedure for a webapp, but none for a desktop application with the required specifications. For this was not technically possible to give more details ... the question and the answer I have avoided more research on this, and I hope will not be deleted because it can be useful for other users with the same doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

watch API calls tell Google servers to make HTTPS calls to your server. Thus your app needs to be running a public web server with a valid SSL certificate. Normally this is not the case for installed apps.

Comment: So, my only option would be a own timer control on possible changes? (with the consequent drainage of 1 million free requests)

Comment: You'll need to poll for changes with get/list.